# Angular 5 issue with 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget' only on prod build. but No issues on Dev build

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

The Console shows this

> ```
> main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not a function.
> at r.(anonymous function).XMLHttpRequest.t.responseBlob.o.function.a.(anonymous function).r.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) [as __zone_symbol__open] (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/polyfills.62d8ac97edff2dddd48f.bundle.js:1:132920)
> at https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/polyfills.62d8ac97edff2dddd48f.bundle.js:1:142082
> at r.(anonymous function).i.(anonymous function) [as open] (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/polyfills.62d8ac97edff2dddd48f.bundle.js:1:133379)
> at t._subscribe (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:647355)
> at t._trySubscribe (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:98272)
> at t.subscribe (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:98101)
> at e.a (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:695746)
> at e._innerSub (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:718260)
> at e._tryNext (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:718184)
> at e._next (https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/main.598d68d658cf204b66cd.bundle.js:1:718007)
> ```

but deployment was successful

you can visit the site [dev server here](https://salty-fjord-85026.herokuapp.com/)

you can look at the code here [github](https://github.com/TheArvindNarayan/angular-ui)

and get in depth understanding of the issue.

thank you all in Advanced

Comment: we need to see your code where it's caused.

Comment: Well it's hard to figure out the exact location because it's failing only in prod mode where all scripts are minified. 

All that I understood after debugging the application main bundle file is - it is failing to call bind method on a function. 

My guess is - variable is either undefined or not a function.

Putting console logs might be useful.

Comment: I have attached my Repo link if you need David and Manoj